# How to add custom controller to extension in vender folder in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model, yii2-user

I have an extension yii2-admin for RBAC, and I would like to add to this extension another controllers, views, models etc. Because in this module I would like to keep all operations who admin like CRUD for User table and for another.

What is the right way to add it? Because to add custom file in folder vendor it's bad way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a module for manage the authorization control  you can do this way

assuming you module is name `auth`

in you config/main.php you assign the module  for auth

```
 'modules' => [
            .....
    'auth'=> [    // your module for authorization (rbac) 
        'class' => 'vendor\your_vendor_name\auth\Module',
    ],
```

then in `vendor\your_vendor_name\auth\Module.php` 
you should have this code for set the controllerNamespace for all the controller related  to auth module

```
  namespace vendor\your_vendor_name\auth;

  use \yii\base\Module as BaseModule;

  /**
   * This is the main module class for the    auth .
   *
   *
   * 
   */
  class Module extends BaseModule
  {
      public $controllerNamespace = 'vendor\your_vendor_name\auth\controllers';

      const VERSION = '1.0.0-dev';

      public function init()
      {
          parent::init();

          // custom initialization code goes here
      }
  }
```

at this point you can add  all the controller you need in

```
 `vendor\your_vendor_name\auth\controllers\`
```

and model in

```
 `vendor\your_vendor_name\auth\models\`
```

and views

in

```
     `vendor\your_vendor_name\auth\views\`
```

eg: for controller in   `vendor\your_vendor_name\auth\controllers\`  i have

```
  AuthAssignmentController.php
  AuthItemChildController.php
  AuthItemController.php
  AuthRuleController.php
  DefaultController.php
```

each of this manage the CRUD for the related  model

Comment: Hello, is it a right way to add files in vendor folder? What will happen if this module will be updated with composer, what will happened with my files which i've added?

Comment: I have a my vendor folder for my  .. extension .(and for extension tha add new functionalites to  others extension). if the extension is from others vendor  how you can extend .. (you have  the same problem) .. .. using a personal vendor folder let you avoid the overwirtten when use composer update